# ¿Cómo contar registros en SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONA(
    ID_PERSONA SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
    ID_CLIENTE SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES PERSONA(ID_PERSONA)
);

CREATE TABLE REGISTRO_SINIESTRO(
    NRO_SINIESTRO SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NRO_POLIZA SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES TITULAR(NRO_POLIZA)
);

CREATE TABLE TITULAR (
    NRO_POLIZA SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES POLIZA(NRO_POLIZA),
    ID_CLIENTE SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES CLIENTE(ID_CLIENTE),
    PRIMARY KEY(NRO_POLIZA, ID_CLIENTE)
);
```

Requiero de ordenar las personas que han tenido más siniestros. Tengo pensado que el Query sería algo así:

```
SELECT ID_PERSONA FROM PERSONA WHERE ID_PERSONA IN (
    SELECT ID_CLIENTE FROM CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE IN (
        SELECT ID_CLIENTE FROM TITULAR WHERE NRO_POLIZA IN (
            SELECT NRO_POLIZA FROM REGISTRO_SINIESTRO
        )
    )
)
```

Pero mi duda es cómo ordenar de mayor a menor las personas dependiendo de la cantidad de siniestros. Cada cliente tiene tantas pólizas. Registro siniestro está asociado a una póliza, y una póliza está asociado a un titular, y un titular está asociado a un cliente, entonces la idea es ordenar de mayor a menor dado cuántos registros_siniestros tiene una persona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal hacerlo con join, con cada coincidencia en cada join se iran repitiendo los reigstros de PERSONA, entonces agrupa y cuenta los registros por grupo, y despues ordena  descendentemente

```
SELECT 
    P.ID_PERSONA,
    COUNT(*) as total
FROM PERSONA as P
JOIN CLIENTE AS C ON C.ID_CLIENTE = P.ID_PERSONA
JOIN TITULAR AS T ON T.ID_CLIENTE  = C.ID_CLIENTE
JOIN REGISTRO_SINIESTRO AS RS ON RS.NRO_POLIZA = T.NRO_POLIZA
GROUP BY P.ID_PERSONA
ORDER BY total DESC
```

mas o menos?